# Lucene 6 Payloads

Tags: lucene, payload

I am trying to work with payloads in Lucene 6 but I am having troubles. The idea is to index payloads and use them in a CustomScoreQuery to check if the payload of a query term matches the payload for the document term.
Here is my payload filter:

```
@Override
public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    if (!this.input.incrementToken()) {
        return false;
    }
    // get the current token
    final char[] token = Arrays.copyOfRange(this.termAtt.buffer(), 0, this.termAtt.length());
    String stoken = String.valueOf(token);
    String[] parts = stoken.split(Constants.PAYLOAD_DELIMITER);
    if (parts.length > 1 && parts.length == 2){
        termAtt.setLength(parts[0].length());
        // the rest is the payload
        BytesRef br = new BytesRef(parts[1]);
        System.out.println(br);
        payloadAtt.setPayload(br);
    }else if (parts.length > 1){
        // skip
    }else{
        // no payload here
        payloadAtt.setPayload(null);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It seems to be adding the payload, however when I try to access the payload in CustomScoreQuery it just keeps returning null.

```
public float determineBoost(int doc) throws IOException{
       float boost = 1f;
       LeafReader reader = this.context.reader();
       System.out.println("Has payloads:" + reader.getFieldInfos().hasPayloads());
       // loop through each location of the term and boost if location matches the payload
       if (reader != null){
           PostingsEnum posting = reader.postings(new Term(this.field, term.getTerm()), PostingsEnum.POSITIONS);
           System.out.println("Term: " + term.getTerm());
           if (posting != null){
               // move to the document currently looking at
               posting.advance(doc);
               int count = 0;
               while (count < posting.freq()){
                   BytesRef load = posting.getPayload();
                   System.out.println(posting);
                   System.out.println(posting.getClass());
                   System.out.println(posting.attributes());
                   System.out.println("Load: " + load);
                   // if the location matches in the term location than boos the term by the boost factor
                   try {
                        if(load != null && term.containLocation(new Payload(load))){
                               boost =  boost * this.boost;
                           }
                    } catch (PayloadException e) {
                        // do not care too much, the payload is unrecognized
                        // this is not going to change the  boost factor
                    }
                   posting.nextPosition();
                   count += 1;
               }
           }
       }
       return boost;
   }
```

For my two tests it keeps stating the load is null. Any suggestions or help?